# How to edit elements with !important

Tags: javascript, weebly

Here is my code:

```
<body class="no-header-page  wsite-page-index  full-width-body-off header-overlay-on alt-nav-off  wsite-theme-light fade-in" style="min-height: 100%; position: relative; height: auto !important; padding-bottom: 64px !important;">
```

I would like to change "padding-bottom: 64px !important;" into "padding-bottom: 0px !important;" using javascript or something else.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just before the closing of the `body` tag add;

```
   <script>
     document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.setProperty("padding-bottom", "0px", "important");
   </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I have tried it and it didn't work. Here's my website: austin0910.weebly.com Thank you!

Comment: Since you have included jQuery in the page, to make it easier include instead `$('body').css('paddingBottom', '0')` The `!important` is unnecessary since you are inlining the style and there is no declaration elsewhere to override that.